# Styled Components Intellisense Not Working

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components, intellisense

The problem is i can't see suggestions while coding styled components. I installed vscode-styled-components but there is no syntax highlighting. Is there anyone having the same problem? I am using VSCode 1.73

I deleted some of my extensions for example Tailwind Intellisense. I thought that maybe it was crushing styled components extension.

Comment: what version of  `vscode-styled-components` you are using ?

Comment: try this version  [vscode-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components)

Comment: I am using the last version 1.7.5

Comment: are you using `Babel ES6/ES7` extention ?

Comment: make sure you are importing **styled** like this `import styled from 'styled-components';`

Comment: I guess it is a common problem for now. They need to update it. This is not for my first time using styled-components. Thanks anyway